# Why is table element covering background image on my report?

Tags: jasper-reports, background-image

I have a watermark set as my background image in the background band of my report. The thing is: there's a table element that covers it. I've tried to set all elements inside it, as well as the table itself to transparent, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Here's the image of the part of the report with the table element.]

What can I do here? I'm not very experienced with Jasper, so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set also all the **styles** used by table and not only the textField's in the table to be transparent.

**Styles transparent**

```
<style name="Table_CH" mode="Transparent"/>
```

**TextField transparent** (if mode is not defined it defaults to transparent)

```
<reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="6b6c8a68-f7fd-453f-a665-32d33be56c51"/>
```

In JasperReports Studio, you find these properties in property tab, under "Appearance"

[image: Studio]

Answer (score 0):

By making Table_TD to Transparent, issue got fixed